# The website structure is change how can I scrape data from website to google sheets?

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, import, fetch

previously this website:
https://fund.fipiran.ir/mf/compare/1

was easily scraped by =importhtml("https://fund.fipiran.ir/mf/compare/1","table",0)

But right now the structure of the website is changed and this formula does not work, what can I do?

Comment: The content on that site is generated by script now, not posted as HTML. So there is no way Google Sheets can access the data.

Comment: Thank you. it seems that there is no way to scrap DATA

Comment: Using a script with json should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned at the comments, the sites that are generated by script can't be scraped:

The content on that site is generated by script now, not posted as HTML. So there is no way Google Sheets can access the data.